# Can I travel from the USA to Italy with just an Italian residence card?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, italy, russian-citizens, us-residents

I am a Russian passport holder, who used to live in Italy but moved to the United States two years ago with my husband.

I want to go see my family who still live in Italy. My Russian passport is going to expire in 1 month, and I plan to renew it while I'm visiting. I was told that, because I have a permesso di soggiorno, the Italian residence card which doesn't expire, I do not need a visa.

Is that correct, that I can enter Italy as my country of residence without any problems? I have a flight ticket, as well, to return in 3 months.

Comment: You have an Italian residence card, but you no longer actually reside in Italy, so yes, you could have problems entering Italy.  Most countries have a rule that residents lose their status after some period of absence; frequently it is six months.  If you had permanent residence, the threshold for disqualification is probably greater, like a year or two. These rules usually operate independently from any expiration date of any document.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably no longer entitled to Italian Residence

> Your EC long-term residence permit may be revoked in the following
>   cases:
>
> - You have acquired it fraudulently.
> - An expulsion measure has been adopted against you.
> - **You no longer fulfil the requirements set for its issue.**
> - **You have been absent from the territory of the European Union for a    period of 12 consecutive months**.
> - You have acquired long-term resident status in another European Union    member State
> - You have been absent from Italy for a period exceeding 6 years.

[polizia di stato](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10723-EC_residence_permit_for_long_term_residents/)

I have made two of the points bold, more information on your Italian resident permit would help us answer better or if you have spent 12 consecutive months outside the EU.

Comment: It says ***may** be revoked* so it might still be good?!? Also OP might have been to EU for a brief visit within those two years? I am honestly unsure how strict their reading of those rules is and how quickly / automatically they will be applied.

Comment: It's also not clear from the question that the residence permit in question was a *long-term* permit.

Comment: OP says it doesn't expire so i presumed that meant permanent. If it was me I would have renewed my Russian passport in the USA and got a Schengen Visitor Visa to be safe.